# Copy and Paste rich text to mailto body in react from clipboard

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, jsx, clipboard

I have a table in which I want the user to be able to send this table via email by copying and paste to mailto subject on click.

Here is a live demo on code sandbox: [copy and paste rich text](https://codesandbox.io/s/copy-and-paste-r5e2j?file=/src/App.js:193-725)

A function to copy and paste rich text to mailto body from clipboard

```
  const copyToClip = () => {
    let range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(tableRef.current);
    let sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
    document.execCommand("Copy");
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    //paste the copied data to mailto body
    document.addEventListener("paste", function (event) {
      var clipText = event.clipboardData.getData("Text");
      window.location = `mailto:?subject=I wanted you to see this site&body=${clipText}`;
    });
  };
```

The expected result when the user clicks the copy button, it opens the client default email and past the table to the body like this below.

[image]

Note: I am able to send the copied data as a string but not a rich-text.

What do I need to to do solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
var clipText = event.clipboardData.getData("Text");
```

to

```
var clipText = encodeURIComponent(event.clipboardData.getData("Text"));
```

Comment: its not even firing that event listener check yourself to the codesanbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/copy-and-paste-r5e2j?file=/src/App.js